# MySQL Query Edge Case - row number fails when only one type of data

Tags: mysql, sql

Here's my Query:

```
select id, Column2, Column3, ..., Column9, Column10, Column11
  from   (select id, Column2, Column3, ..., Column9, Column10, Column11,
        @num := if(@group = Column3, @num + 1, 1) as row_number,
        @group := Column3 as dummy from TABLE order by Column3) as x
  where
            row_number <= 8
            and Column9 = 'value1'
            and Column10 = 'value2'
  limit 1000 for update;
```

It works perfectly when the number of distinct values for Column3 is greater than one. I can have thousands of rows in the table, but if all have the same Column3 value, this query returns nothing.

If I then add in a new row with Column3 being something distinct, it works again (only to fail next time).

Some background if it helps: Column3 would be a foreign key if I set that up. So the query's goal is to spread the data over Column3 - grab as many distinct groups of 8 as long as the total rows returned is less than 1000 (in production these all change with each query and as far as I can tell, it works, except this case).

**EDIT:** I've partly figured it out. It's related a MySQL specific feature I took advantage of that is much quicker than the quadratic row_number().

```
select @num := if(@group = Column3, @num + 1, 1) as row_number,
    @group := Column3 from runTimeURLStorage;
```

Run the above query over and over and @num just increases in number every call unless this is performed:

```
set @num  = 1;
```

The 'set @num  = 1;' is called under the hood when there are multiple values for Column3. I may just have a call to 'set @num  = 1;' on the same connection...

Comment: Is it significant that the column names are enumerated?

Comment: are you asking about the naming of Column2, Column3, etc? If so, I changed the actual column names thinking it would make it easier to focus on the query itself.

Comment: I guess I don't understand why 'column11' or the ellipsis are included within the query.

Comment: because all the columns are used in the application, but only a couple are used in the query. so I replaced the middle columns that just take up space with the ellipsis

Comment: At this point, I would suggest (as I usually do) providing proper DDLs, and or an sqlfiddle TOGETHER WITH THE DESIRED result set. leave out any extraneous material (col4 thru col8, and col11, for instance)

Answer (score 0):

I have to make a call to:

```
set @num  = 1;
```

on the same connection before executing my main query in the event that there is only one distinct Column3 value, otherwise MySQL caches the value for @num from previous invocations.